# "cannot find symbol" while compile opencv

Tags: java, opencv, compiler-errors

I try to compile Opencv using this tutorial - link text When i promt 
`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..`
i get the following information

-- Java: -- ant: /usr/local/bin/ant (ver 1.9.3) 
-- JNI: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers 
-- Java tests: YES

Next step is make -j8 abort at 88% with error:

```
    [ 88%] Generating opencv-248.jar
    [javac] /Users/zhuk/android+opencv/opencv/opencv/src/org/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d.java:9:  error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import org.opencv.core.Mat;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Mat
    [javac]   location: package org.opencv.core
```

cmake version 2.8.11.2. Mac OS 10.9.2.

How can I compile OpenCV?

Comment: In general it means that library (eg. opencv-248.jar) which holds that file org.opencv.core.Mat is not in the classpath.

Comment: Yes, I think about it, but in folder `src/org/opencv/core/` not exist file `Mat.java`. This file must be generate while opencv building, but it not created.

Comment: if you cannot find java folder see this thread - http://answers.opencv.org/question/7958/no-opencv_java244-in-javalibrarypath/

Answer (score 1):

solution is very simple!!! 
Trouble was in symbol "+" in path!!!

> /Users/zhuk/**android+opencv**/opencv/opencv/

replace opencv path solve the problem.